# Expected entropy in $P(x)\oplus x$ for random $x$, where $P$ is a random permutation

Tags: entropy, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Let $P$ be a random permutation of $n>1$ bits. Let $F$ be the function on the same domain $\{0,1\}^n$, defined by $F(x)=P(x)\oplus x$. When $P$ is a block cipher with key a message block, that's the [Davies-Meyer construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies.E2.80.93Meyer) of a one-way compression function, a variant of which being used in MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-2.

Let $H_F$ be the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) (in bits) of the source $F(x)$ where $x$ is a vector of $n$ random unbiased independent bits. That is
$$\begin{align*}
H_F&=\sum_{y\in F(\{0,1\}^n)}-\Pr(F(x)=y)\cdot\log_2\big(\Pr(F(x)=y)\big)\\
\\
& = n-{1\over2^n}\cdot\sum_{y\in F(\{0,1\}^n)}\big(\#{\{x, F(x)=y)\}}\big)\cdot\log_2\big(\#{\{x, F(x)=y)\}}\big)
\\
& = n-{1\over2^n}\cdot\sum_{2\le\,j\,\le2^n}\big(\#{\{y,(\#\{x:F(x)=y\})=j\}}\big)\cdot j\cdot\log_2(j)
\end{align*}$$
Note: $\#{\{x, F(x)=y)\}}$ of the 2<sup>nd</sup> equation is the number of preimages of vector $y$; and $\#{\{y,(\#\{x:F(x)=y\})=j\}}$ of the 3<sup>rd</sup> is the number of vectors with exactly $j$ preimages.

$H_F$ can be from $0$ (when $P$ happens to be XOR with some constant) to $n$ bits (when $F$ happens to be a permutation, e.g. for $P:$ $00\to00$, $01\to10$, $10\to11$, $11\to01$ ).

Let $H(n)$ be the expected value of $H_F$; that is, the average of $H_F$ over all $(2^n)!$ permutations $P$. A plausible conjecture is that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{H(n)\over n}=1$$
How to prove this, and what's a first order approximation of $n-H(n)$ for large $n$?

---

If $F$ was a random function, we'd have $n-H(n)\approx0.8272\dots$ starting with moderate $n$ according to my analysis [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24672/555). But I fail to rigorously derive that for the much narrower class of $F$ in the question.

Comment: Trying to understand your formulation. Is your definition of entropy related to the image size of the map $P(x)+x$? So entropy of the "source" $F(x)$ is the entropy of the output of $F$ with input $x$ uniform.

Comment: In case the term is useful: A permutation P such that P(x) ^ x also defines a permutation is called an orthomorphism.

Comment: Do you have any numerical results for $n - H(n)$ for large $n$? I'd like to be able to check my theoretical result before posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Aleph: No. But I'd be mildly surprised if the limit was not the same as for a random function, 0.827245389153..

Comment: @fgrieu Ok, then I'll post the answer showing that it is the same. Although I think you've actually shown it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, your question boils down to: "What is the probability distribution of the number of fixed points of a random permutation?"

As you note in the question,

$$H_F = n-{1\over2^n}\cdot\sum_{2\le\,j\,\le2^n}\big(\#{\{y,(\#\{x:F(x)=y\})=j\}}\big)\cdot j\cdot\log_2(j).$$

I'll rewrite this using probabilities for brevity:

$$n - H_F = \sum_{2\le\,j\,\le2^n}\Pr\big(|F^{-1}(y)|=j\big)\cdot j\cdot\log_2(j).$$

where $|F^{-1}(y)|$ is the size of the preimage of $y$. Importantly, this entire sum is a random variable and below we take the expectation over the random function $F$.

Taking expectations, we get

$$\mathbf{E}\left[n - H_F\right] = \sum_{2\le\,j\,\le2^n}\mathbf E\left[\Pr\big(|F^{-1}(y)|=j]\big)\right]\cdot j\cdot\log_2(j).$$

Note that $\mathbf{E}\left[\Pr\left(|F^{-1}(y)| = j\right)\right]$ is independent of $y$, so we might as well compute $\mathbf{E}\left[\Pr\left(|F^{-1}(0)| = j\right)\right]$.
Since $F(x) = P(x) \oplus x = 0$ iff $P(x) = x$, we are really looking for the probability distribution of the number of fixed points of a random permutation.

It is well known that as $n \to \infty$, this distribution is Poisson with expectation 1, that is:

$$\mathbf{E}\left[\Pr\left(|F^{-1}(0)| = j\right)\right] \approx \frac{1}{ej!}.$$

An exact value (for finite $n$) could be obtained in terms of the Rencontres numbers.

Hence,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{E}\left[n - H_F\right]
= \sum_{j = 2}^{\infty} \frac{j\log_2(j)}{ej!}.$$

Note that I've implicitly made use of the bounded convergence theorem, that is, since $\Pr\left(|F^{-1}(y)| = j\right)$ is bounded above for every $n$, and since

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr\left(|F^{-1}(0)| = j\right) = \frac{1}{ej!},$$

we also have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{E}\left[\Pr\left(|F^{-1}(y)| = j\right)\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr\left(|F^{-1}(y)| = j\right)\right].$$

Comment: I hope I didn't miss anything. To me it seems like you actually did most of the work.

Comment: The step "Taking expectations.." initially made me uncomfortable since the $\Pr\big(|F^{-1}(y)|=j\big)$ are dependent; but that is definitely OK. I like how you get rid of $y$ and get to the probability distribution of the number of fixed points of a random permutation. And I'm happy to know the precise theorem used when getting to the limit. Yes I had some intuition of the formula, but you proved it. Also, with the Rencontre numbers, you give a way to compute things for small $n$.

Answer (score 2):

All functions (including permutations) mapping a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ to itself can be uniquely represented by polynomials (via Lagrange Interpolation, possibly followed by reduction modulo $x^{q}-x.$ When $q=2^n,$ the linear permutations $F(x)=x+a,$ for $a\neq 0,$are exactly the type of polynomial that give zero entropy in your formulation since $F(x)+x=a$ a constant.

Focusing only on $q=2^n$ due to crypto applications, we don't know explicit representation of many other permutations but some include certain monomials $F(x)=x^{e}$ with special conditions on exponent $e,$ as well as families such as Dickson's polynomials, which don't have an $x$ term in their polynomial and won't suffer the weakness of zero entropy for $F(x)+x$. As for computing what fraction of overall permutation polynomials have an $x$ in their polynomial expression, it's likely to be a difficult problem.

**Edit:** *The below is redundant, due to your comment, the above is still relevant but I can take it to a comment if requested, it's a bit long.*

If we model the map $F(x)=P(x)+x$ by a random mapping instead of a random permutation from $A=\{0,1\}^n$ to itself, then the number of points $y$ in $A$ that have no preimages, i.e., there is no $x\in A$ with $f(x)=y,$ is on average equal to $e^{-1}\#A=\frac{2^n}{e}.$

This would mean that the expected size of the range of $F$ is $$\mathbb{E}[F(A)]=(1-e^{-1}) 2^n\approx 0.6321 \cdot 2^n$$ yielding $$H(n)\approx n+\log_2(0.6321)= n-0.66172,$$
so as you predicted the  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}H(n)/n=1.$

References for this type of argument include Sedgewick and Flajolet's book *An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms*, and the paper "Random Mapping Statistics" by Flajolet and Odlyzko in Eurocrypt'89, but a very readable account is in Chapter 5 of Riordan's classic book *An Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis*, from 1958.

Comment: There is a gap at the line reading _"yielding"_: the entropy $E_F$ does not only depend on the number $m$ of points in $\{0,1\}^n$ that have no preimage by $F$ (at least, for an arbitrary function $F$); for a given $m$, the entropy will be higher if the other $2^n-m$ points have $\lfloor{2^n\over 2^n-m}\rfloor$ or $\lceil{2^n\over 2^n-m}\rceil$ preimages, than if $2^n-m-1$ points have a single preimage and a single other point has $m+1$ preimages. I believe that makes the $0.66172$ significantly off.

Comment: I see, so you actually want the expected entropy of $2^{-n}(N_0,\ldots,N_{2^n-1})$ where $N_y=\#\{x:F(x)=y\}$ using integer notation for $y$ for simplicity.

Comment: I think that the second formula for $H_F$ in the [question as now modified](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/43442/9) matches what you mean in the above comment.

Comment: In the first paragraph, $a = 0$ also does give one of the 0-entropy results ($x + 0 + x = 0$ in a field with characteristic 2). In general, from the number of elements which are not in the image of $F$, you can not calculate the entropy of the image of $F$: The actual distribution of the elements in the image matter just as much as those which are not in the image.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks, very useful. I'll modify my answer when I get some time soon

Answer (score 2):

The probability for $0$ *not* being in the image of $x\mapsto P(x)\oplus x$ is for big $n$ about $\frac{1}{e}$, as it is equivalent to $P$ being fixed-point-free.

By symmetry (replace $P$ by $P_k(x) := P(x)\oplus k$ for fixed $k$) the probability of any value $k$ to be *not* in the image of $P$ for big $n$ is hence also about $\frac{1}{e}$.

Phrased differently, the random variable $X_k$ defined as $X_k=1$ if $k$ is in the image of $x\mapsto P(x)\oplus x$ and $X_k=0$ otherwise has expectation about $1-\frac{1}{e}$.

Summing over the $X_k$ for all $k$ one gets that the expected size of the image is about $\frac{e-1}{e}\cdot 2^n$.

For a given size $s = \sum X_k$ of the image, the entropy is maximal if every value in the image is equally likely, and then the entropy $H_{\rm max} = \log_2 s$. Hence by [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality) $$\mathbb{E}(H_{\rm max}) = \mathbb{E}(\log_2(s)) \le \log_2(\mathbb{E}(s)) \approx \log_2(\frac{e-1}{e}\cdot 2^n) = n-\log_2(\frac{e}{e-1})$$ giving an *upper bound* for the entropy.

[The entropy is minimal for given $s$, if all but one of the images has a unique preimage and all other values are mapped to the one. It is not difficult to derive the formula for $H_{\rm min}$, but as the second derivative of $H_{\rm min}$ is negative, applying Jensen's inequality doesn't yield anything useful. Anyway, I would expect the true entropy be closer to $H_{\rm max}$ than $H_{\rm min}$.]

---

**Remark**: I'd expect that for permutations the entropy is *lower* than for general functions, because of the following heuristics: If one restricts oneself to (the relatively tiny subset of) all linear functions rsp. bijections, then $x\mapsto P(x)\oplus x$ is bijective if and only if the linear map $P$ does *not* have the eigenvalue $1$. The restriction to permutations forbids the eigenvalue $0$, which increases the chance of having $1$ as eigenvalue.

---

Towards a lower bound of $\frac{n+1}{2}$ for the average entropy: If the image has size $s$ the entropy is minimal in the case described above in the brackets, where one finds $$H_\min(s) = \frac{(s-1)\cdot n}{2^n} - (1-\frac{s-1}{2^n})\cdot\log_2(1-\frac{s-1}{2^n}).$$ As $H_\min$ increases with $s$ one gets the *lower* bound $$\mathbb{E}(H) \ge \mathbb{E}(H_\min) \ge \mathrm{Prob}(s>2^{n-1})\cdot H_\min(2^{n-1}+1) = \mathrm{Prob}(s>2^{n-1})\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}.$$

Proving $\mathrm{Prob}(s>2^{n-1})\to 1$ for $n\to\infty$ I leave to you, as this idea is anyway based on your comment.

Comment: If the size of the image is $s\approx{e-1\over e}\cdot 2^n$, and (maximizing the entropy) every value in the image is _as about equally likely as possible given that_ $s$ , then $2s-2^n$ values have exactly 1 preimage, and $2^n-s$ values have exactly 2 preimages. That yields (by the third equality in the question) $H_F=n-{1\over2^n}\cdot(2^n-s)\cdot2$. Thus $H_F\le n-0.736$ for large $n$ and a restriction to those $F$ with (close to) the expected size of the image. However I fail to see how we move from there to the full class of $F$ in the question, and/or to average entropy.

Comment: Your sharper estimate with $0.736$ works only for sizes $s>2^{n-1}$. Taking $\log_2$ gives always an upper bound for the entropy given the image size $s$. Now apply Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I think Jensen tells us the opposite: the average entropy is lower than the entropy in the average case, so the latter gives only an upper bound, not the desired lower bound.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I have written a [reformulated question at cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/259830/8469); I had some precious few good experiences there.