# Does applying a "PushEntropy"-function increase security of a private key?

Tags: entropy, cryptocurrency, pki

I was just reviewing the source-code of the [NBitcoin-package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin/). As far as i can see when you create a new bitcoin-keypair

`Key privateKey = new Key();`

(without passing some random data to be used as private key generated by yourself) then the library generates a private key using a random-number-generator for you. Very usual. But then i stumbled across the fact that the output of the random-number-generator will not directly be used as private key: NBitcoin also applies a [PushEntropy](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/RandomUtils.cs#L70)-function on this byte-array:

```
private static void PushEntropy(byte[] data)
{
    if (!UseAdditionalEntropy || additionalEntropy == null || data.Length == 0)
        return;
    int pos = entropyIndex;
    var entropy = additionalEntropy;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] ^= entropy[pos % 32];
        pos++;
    }
    entropy = Hashes.SHA256(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] ^= entropy[pos % 32];
        pos++;
    }
    entropyIndex = pos % 32;
}
```

I understand what this function does, but I do not understand why we need this function to generate a private-key.

Why is a cryptographically secure random-number-generator (to generate the private key aka `data`-bytearray) not enough?

Does this function increase security in any kind?

Comment: We had a similar question, need to be found. It is a little failsafe if there is some problem on the random-number-generator ( there are/were lots of [systems with poor entropy](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239397/86735) and bugs) the hash can randomize it though cannot change the entropy of the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is a cryptographically secure random-number-generator (to generate the private key aka data-bytearray) not enough?

A Cryptographically Secure ***True*** Random Number Generator *would be* enough. This code uses a belt-and-suspenders approach. This is common in RNGs, in recognition of the fact that RNGs are traditionally one of the most brittle components in crypto implementations (see e.g.[SmartFacts](https://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/)).

The intention appears to be: if [`UseAdditionalEntropy`](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/RandomUtils.cs#L43) is at it's default of `true`, and `additionalEntropy` has been set with something unguessable or/and truly random by calling one of two [forms](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/RandomUtils.cs#L93) of [`AddEntropy`](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/RandomUtils.cs#L100)

1. Try to save the day if initially `data` contains something guessable, by mixing the two (in the first loop)
2. Make it hard to "walk back" from the result, by applying a non-reversible transformation. When `data` is 32-byte and `entropyIndex` starts at zero, this transformation is $\mathtt{data}\mapsto\operatorname{SHA-256}(\mathtt{data})\oplus\mathtt{data}$. Given the output, the only hope to find the input is by enumeration of likely input values¹.

Step 1 can conceivably backfire, e.g. if `data` passed is the SHA-256 hash of what was previously passed to `AddEntropy`.

Step 2 slightly reduces the entropy (by less than 1 bit if `data` was full-entropy, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24672/555); and negligibly so if `data` was less than full-entropy), but in the context that's fine.

> Does this function increase security in any kind?

It does, if `Random.GetBytes` of the [calling context](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/RandomUtils.cs#L141) has a flaw, and `AddEntropy` was used and passed something secret (including something random and independent of what `Random.GetBytes` outputs; or just a secret constant generated at random at time of installation). As long as `PushEntropy`,  `additionalEntropy` and `entropyIndex` remain `private` (thus not accidentally callable), this precaution is unlikely to accidentally backfire.

---

¹ If we changed `+=` to `^=` in the final mixing step of the round function of SHA-256, this transformation would be reversible. And it would be dangerously close to reversible if we changed `^=` to `-=` in the code shown.