# Does using pseudorandom generator more than once cause security loss?

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-generator

[image]
Everytime we use the generator with itself there is security loss. Even if this loss is not enough to loose all cryptographic security, there is still some small loss in security. Is there any way to calculate as to how much do we loose in aspect to security?

Comment: You are using the PRNG (except perhaps the outer one) avec a PRF with identical input and output width; thus this is comparable to the setup of [that question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15068/555) with a good answer. See [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24672/555) for the entropy loss after 1 iteration.