# Iterative hashing increases number of security bits?

Tags: hash, entropy, signal-protocol

Whatsapp uses 5200 iterations of SHA-512 over user's public key and identity 
according to [WhatsApp Security Whitepaper](https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61/68135620_760356657751682_6212997528851833559_n.pdf/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf).

I wonder why?

According to: [Why iterate 5200 times when computing Safety Numbers in Signal?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195761/why-iterate-5200-times-when-computing-safety-numbers-in-signal)  this question on Information Security.SE: It is to increase security bits to 112.

I do understand why 30 digit number has $\approx 99$ bits entropy and so $\approx 99$ security bits.

$$\log_2(10)*30 \approx 99$$

But how does iterative hashing affects security bits? It does not affect entropy as far as I understand.

Math in the post indeed shows:

$\log_2(10^{30} * 5200) \approx 112$. Which is recommended number of security bits at [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/en/4/)

Moreover, Signal source code comments state that too on the [source code](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java/blob/ea0ffa41ec945836e44b9472c43467f9c6c1810c/java/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/libsignal/fingerprint/NumericFingerprintGenerator.java#L35)

Where can I read more on why '5200' iterations of hashing placed *into* the 'log' as multiplication and why does it affect security bits at all?

Comment: Adding 1 bit to the strength of a "password" (say, by flipping a coin and appending `0` or `1` based on the result) doubles the number of hashes it would take to crack the password. Doubling the number of iterations also doubles the number of SHA-512 hashes needed to crack a password. The error is that you conflate security and entropy. We treat password stretching as increasing the effective strength of a password (hash). We do not say that the entropy of the outcome of the hash increases, no matter how many times it's iterated. (This isn't quite a password, but it doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does iterative hashing affects security (measured in) bits?

It does so by increasing the number of operations likely required to solve the problem by brute force, because an *operation* is what's iterated in each attempt of break.

> (iterative hashing) does not affect entropy

Indeed, iterative hashing does not increase¹ entropy. It can still increase security.

> $n$-bit security means that adversary needs to perform $2^n$ operations to break the system.

Yes, for some definition of *operation*, and certainty to break the system.

If there's an attack with $N$ operations that succeeds with probability $p$, and $p$ grows linearly with $N$ until $p=1$ as in key search, then the system has at most $$n=\log_2(N/p)=\log_2(N)-\log_2(p)\text{ bit security}$$

This formula works including for low $p$ and any $N\ge1$. Customarily, it is used also when $p$ only grows about linearly with $N$ until $p$ reaches a non-negligible value, e.g. because $p=e^{-N_0/N}$ as in preimage search.

The question's Whatsapp system re-formats 32-byte ECC public keys into 30-decimal digit strings that appear nearly uniformly distributed. The main design goal is to make it hard to generate a private key which matching public key re-formats to one (or more) given strings obtained by re-formatting one (or more) target public key(s); that is, make second preimage search difficult.

A brute force preimage attack against this system generates key pairs; hashes the public key 5200 times with SHA-512; and makes a test against the targeted value(s). Each private key test has probability $p=10^{-30}$ to match a given string. Each test costs 5200 iterations of SHA-512 and comparatively little else (an increment of the private key, an ECC point addition of a constant point to the previous public key, typically one (at most 6) comparison against 5 digits of the given string of the modular reduction modulo $10^5$ of part of the SHA-512 hash).

It follows that security is $\log_2(5200)+30\log_2(10)\approx112.00$-bit when the cost is counted in SHA-512 hashes, which is the natural metric here, and there's a single target key. For $s$ target strings/keys, the probability of success of each test is increased by a factor $s$, thus security is reduced by $\log_2(s)$ bit.

---

Notes:

A [former version](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/77947/13) of this answer was about the security increase with increased iteration count in a cryptosystem where there are sizably much other operations beyond iterated hashing. That's not relevant in the question's context, thus removed.

¹ : The simplest forms of iterative hashing, including the one in the question's Whatsapp context even slightly reduce entropy; see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15068/555).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you please explain what's $i_0$? As far as I understand – security level, n-bit security means that adversary needs to perform $2^n$ operations to crash break the system. So original security level was $\log_2(10^{30}) \approx 99$ Adding number of hash iterations adds number of operations $\log_2(10^{30}*5200) \approx 112$. Does *time* affects 'security level' bits in any matter ?

Comment: @Alexander Smirnov : I have revised to answer for the Whatsapp context. I'll further tweak it, but not right now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you refer is unfortunately *misleading*. Also the comment in the source code is *misleading*. The answer you refer does not say that *entropy* is higher. It uses wording *the bits of security* which is not standard and is misleading. Some use wording *security strength* which approximately means *to break this algorithm by brute-forcing one needs to try 2^(that many) values*. What the author of the answer means is that CPU time needed to calculate a hash with iterations is approximately the same as a *single* calculation of a longer hash.

But entropy depends on the size of the hash space only. And in particular the probability of hash collisions remains the same.

I answered now the question you refer (see your link and there my answer) and hope I explained it better what some people mean by such misleading wording.

Comment: "But entropy depends on the size of the hash space only." No. If you have a non-uniform statistical distribution of input values, then the hash has less entropy. The size of the input space only can be used in entropy calculations *instead of a probability mass function* if it is known that the possible value of an unknown input can be modeled as a uniform distribution. It's probabilities, not counts.

Comment: @FutureSecurity: You are absolutely right. It''s probabilities, to be more precisely - *distribution of probabilities* :) But here is only a brief version of my answer in the thread referred. I didn't want to duplicate it. And if you read that answer you will see the remark *assuming that hashes are distributed equally* :) I will keep *this* answer as it is, brief, expecting that the main discussion will happen in the thread referred.