# Can HKDF be used in place of a cryptographic hash function?

Tags: hash, key-derivation

For context, I'm making a non-production grade reference implementation of the [balloon hash function](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/027) using the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto). In order to make it less susceptible to [certain attacks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7961977) on common memory hard KDFs, the number of memory blocks should be reduced, meaning their size should increase. I am however restricted in the choice of cryptographic functions to the functions defined in the SubtleCrypto interface of the Web Crypto API. And that leads to the question:

Can HKDF be used in place of a cryptographic hash function? None of the SHA1 or SHA2 hash functions have large enough outputs for this application. Would a longer output, say 2048-4096 bits, from HKDF-SHA512 have near equivalent security properties to plain SHA512, or would they differ in some aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can HKDF be used in place of a cryptographic hash function?

**Yes**.

HKDF is defined ([there](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc5869.txt.pdf#page=3)) from HMAC and a hash. $H(M)$ computed as
$$\operatorname{HKDF-Expand}(\operatorname{HKDF-Extract}(\mathrm{salt},M),\mathrm{info},512)$$
for fixed small (possibly empty) constant bytestrings $\mathrm{salt}$ and $\mathrm{info}$, and SHA-512 as the underlying hash for HMAC, will behave essentially as a 4096-bit hash about as strong as SHA-512 is.

Arguably, there is a little loss in the possible number of possible outputs, and the number of values possible for each 512-bit output segment, but it's computationally impossible to observe, and arguably within 2 of 512 bit anyway by arguments on the tune of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15068/555).

Problem is that each HKDF producing 8×512 bits costs 20‡ SHA-512 compression functions (for small $M$). In a Balloon (or other memory-hard function) context, I'm afraid this relatively high cost shifts the balance in favor of adversaries that can implement SHA-512 at blazing speed. I'd rather cut corners quite a lot on the cryptographic security of the hash in favor of a faster hash, so that more of the computing power goes to memory accesses.

---

‡ That's assuming a careful implementation caching the first block in HMAC whenever possible; otherwise I get 36. Both counts need cross-checking.

Comment: Yes okay, I understand that then and HKDF does not sound like the most efficient then. A cheaper hash sounds better for this application.

Comment: I cross checked the counts and I get 18. I count 2 hashes for the extraction and 2*n for the expansion, n being 8 in this case.

Comment: @n-l-i: There are 18 SHA-512 for sure; but each hashes 2 blocks (hence my 36 without caching). When we count compression functions of SHA-512 as I do, even with caching (and precomputation for $\mathrm{salt}$), we must account for the compression of $\mathrm{PRK}\oplus\mathrm{ipad}$ in the first SHA-512 of the HMAC producing the first output block, and the compression of $\mathrm{PRK}\oplus\mathrm{opad}$ in the second SHA-512 of the same HMAC. Both can be cached for the 7 HMAC producing the next output blocks. Whatever, we agree on the order of magnitude, and that it is an issue.